# Clicking/Moving mouse produces beeps, laggy keyboard key presses on pc start

Tags: windows-8, memory, motherboard, lag

I can't for the love of god figure this out. When starting my computer, sometimes when I open an application, my computer comes to a halt. These things happen:

-Pressing a button on my mouse produces a beep for the down press and another beep for the up press.

-If it's bad enough, just moving the mouse will produce a beep. But that hasn't happened for a while.

-Keyboard typing is laggish. It types what I type but one letter per 5 seconds about.

-System still loads in the background. People on mumble/skype can still talk in real time. Youtube still plays and buffers fine.

To fix it I just have to keep restarting my computer and trying the same thing until it doesn't happen. Does anyone know what would cause this or how to diagnose it?

Specs:

```
Windows 8 64-bit
32GB Ram
ASUS Rampage IV Extreme Mobo
2x Nvidia 670 GPU
1000W PSU - Corsair
i7-3730K CPU
Logitech Mouse and KB
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! As-Is this "Question" is way too vague. What have you tried already? Disk checks?  Disabling Services?  Does it do it in Safe Mode?  Does it still do it after a fresh reinstall of Windows?

Comment: I encountered the same issue, both Windows 7 and Windows 8. I was so angry to find it occurring after installing the new OS. I had all the same symptoms as you and after some research, found out it was an issue with "Filter Keys" [Here is a post](http://www.evonsdesigns.com/2013/07/keyboard-mouse-lag-constant-beeping.html) on how to turn it off. I would reopen this question if I could. Googling the issue shows it is a pretty common problem.

Comment: I've also had this exact issue, I don't think it's "too narrow" and should probably be re-opened. I encountered this issue after I was remote-desktoped into the machine, closed the remote session (without signing out), and then logged in to the actual machine (not in a remote session). Restarting the machine resolved the issue.

Comment: I agree about it not being "too narrow." I found this because I have the same problem. If it weren't closed, maybe someone it would have been figured out here.

Comment: Could a moderator please re-open this question? It is not hyper-specific. I am in a different geographic area, 8 years later, and using Win11 (vs Win8). I've had this problem for three years. The symptoms are identical to those described. If I had the solution then I would post here if the question were not closed. I imagine others might have done the same in the 8 years since this question was asked, if it were not closed. Please, moderators, reopen this question, so that we--the readers of SU who suffer from this issue--may one day share the answer with each other. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The puzzling part is that it only happens on start up but you don't give much to go on  but

Check your MSCONFIG and disable the start up programs (if you're happy to do so) which you don't need.

Check your Task Scheduler to see if anything is being kicked off on start

These are things to check any way although I'm less confident as your issue is only on start up:

Update your BIOS

When you can get on your machine and the mouse works as expected, update your drivers (or even roll them back for the keyboard/mouse)

Borrow another keyboard/mouse and see if the problem persists.

Use different USB ports for keyboard and mouse (assuming they're both USB).

If this still fails, it could be a faulting motherboard!